# How to make a background server request?

Tags: android

I need to make an android app which can request some data from the server and post that again to another server. I want to perform all this even when app is closed.

Comment: you can use Background Service for this

Comment: Have you even tried to do that?

Comment: first of all you need to google your requirement

Answer (score 0):

you can run your app in Background using [Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)

For data sending you can study about [AsyncTask Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)